# Redirect to a page after logging in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website that uses Wordpress and Woocommerce and i want to redirect the user to a custom URL after he do log in with the WooCommerce login page.

I'm new to programming and wordpress, sorry if my question looks dumb

I searched for the solution in the internet and found this:

```
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
        $redirect_to = 'CustomURLhere';
    return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

but it didn't work, it gave me a message that my website have an error

Comment: Coule be a bunch of different things that went wrong with that code. Maybe it's in the wrong location. Did you put it in the `functions.php` file? In your `wp-config.php` you can set `WP_DEBUG` to `true`. That should give you a better error output. You can update your question with that error message then.

Answer (score 0):

i think you don't need to use "$request" and "$user" for login redirection, just try to add this code at the bottom of your functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 9999 );
function my_login_redirect( $redirect_to) {
   $redirect_to = 'CustomURLhere'; // don't forget to change this with your URL ;)
   return $redirect_to;
}
```

Hope it helps !